# WordPress plugin throwing warning when wp_redirect is used

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a plugin where user will submit a form. The form submits to the same page. Form data handling code is implemented by checking the condition-

```
if ( !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'customer_add_new')
```

Then the data is validated and entered to database using $wpdb->insert.

After that, I want to pass a variable to the URL, so that success message can be displayed and user can be stopped from re-submitting the form by refreshing the page. For that, I used-

```
$url = add_query_arg( array(
    'customer_add_new' => 'success'
    ) );
wp_redirect( $url );
exit();
```

But this code is throwing the following error-

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at E:\wamp\www\cp_plugin\wp-includes\class.wp-scripts.php:343) in E:\wamp\www\cp_plugin\wp-includes\pluggable.php on line 1216
```

I have successfully used the same code in the theme for this very same project. But the functionality was better suited for a plugin, than for a theme.

Comment: You need to put your form handling code before output of any HTML, as redirection works by modifying header and once headers sent to the browser, can't be modified. For solution look at this [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76991/wp-redirect-not-working-after-submitting-form/76993#76993).

Comment: @malviya, the form handling code does not output any HTML. It just validates all the data and enters it into the db.

Comment: Not necessarily your form handling code, any code that produces HTML will cause this error, as WordPress has many pluggables.

Comment: @rmalviya If that is the case, how do I figure out what part is causing the problem? Also, please read the edit I added to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hook `admin_post` will help you. Works the same as `admin-ajax.php`.

Change form action to `<?php echo admin_url('admin-post.php'); ?>` and create hooks:

```
add_action( 'admin_post_{action}', 'funct' );
add_action( 'admin_post_nopriv_{action}', 'funct' );

function funct() {
    if ( wp_verify_nonce( 'some_nonce', 'some_action' ) ) {
        // Your code using $_POST
        // And create wp_redirect();
    }
}
```

This might help you.

Comment: This looks like it will work. But I cannot figure out the file structure needed. I want the forms on the public-facing side. Currently, I am using shortcode to include the files 'customers/customer-add-to-database.php' and 'customers/customer-add-new.php', in that order. First file contains code which handles the submitted data and second file contains the form itself. Now where should I put the add_action, and where to put the function? I tried keeping the current structure, but it gives me 'Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback'.

Comment: Is there any way to manage it within the plugin itself? I mean without touching the theme?

Comment: Yes, sure. Put this code in your main plugin file. If you`re using OOP sctructure you should add this actions on __contruct method of your main class.